# Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, react-router, react-redux

I am not sure why my project is giving me Could not find store error when I try to do normal start. But when I do start-dev, which is devServer it works fine. Probably easier to show you in code.

here is the whole error

```
Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Layout)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Layout)".
```

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/.bin/babel-node --presets react,es2015 src/server.js",
    "start-dev": "npm run start-dev-hmr",
    "start-dev-single-page": "node_modules/.bin/http-server src/static",
    "start-dev-hmr": "node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --progress --inline --hot --open",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/.bin/webpack -p"
  },
"dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.11.4",
    "babel-core": "^6.13.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.13.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
    "cross-env": "^3.1.4",
    "css-loader": "^0.27.3",
    "ejs": "^2.5.1",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.0",
    "react": "^15.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.3",
    "react-router": "^2.8.1",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.14.1"
  },
```

reducer.js

```
const action_types = require('./action_types');
import json from 'json!../../lang.json';


const initialState = {
  content: json.en // Loads default language content (en) as an initial state
};

const reducer = function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case action_types.SWITCH_LANGUAGE:
      return {
        content: json[action.language]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

module.exports = reducer;
```

AppRouter.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import routes from '../routes';
import Layout from './Layout';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
const content = require('../Action/reducer');
const store = createStore(content);


export default class AppRoutes extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)}/>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

routes.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'
import Layout from './components/Layout';
import IndexPage from './components/IndexPage';
import AthletePage from './components/AthletePage';
import Notfound from './components/Notfound';
import Pricing from './components/Pricing/Pricing'

const routes = (
  <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
    <IndexRoute component={IndexPage}/>
    <Route path="pricing" component={Pricing}/>
    <Route path="*" component={Notfound}/>
  </Route>
);

export default routes;
```

Layout.js

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

// const actions = require('../Action/actions');
import * as actions from '../Action/actions';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class Layout extends React.Component {
  handleSwitchLang(targetLang) {
    this.props.switchLanguage(targetLang);
  }

  render() {
    let switchLanguage = this.props.switchLanguage;
    let content = this.props.content;
    return (
      <div className="app-container">
        some ui code
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { content: state.content }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Layout);
```

Server.js

```
    'use strict';

import path from 'path';
import { Server } from 'http';
import Express from 'express';
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { match, RouterContext } from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes';
import NotFoundPage from './components/NotFoundPage';

// initialize the server and configure support for ejs templates
const app = new Express();
const server = new Server(app);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

// define the folder that will be used for static assets
app.use(Express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));

// universal routing and rendering
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  match(
    { routes, location: req.url },
    (err, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {

      // in case of error display the error message
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send(err.message);
      }

      // in case of redirect propagate the redirect to the browser
      if (redirectLocation) {
        return res.redirect(302, redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search);
      }

      // generate the React markup for the current route
      let markup;
      if (renderProps) {
        // if the current route matched we have renderProps
        markup = renderToString(<RouterContext {...renderProps}/>);
      } else {
        // otherwise we can render a 404 page
        markup = renderToString(<NotFoundPage/>);
        res.status(404);
      }

      // render the index template with the embedded React markup
      return res.render('index', { markup });
    }
  );
});

// start the server
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production';
server.listen(port, err => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
  console.info(`Server running on http://localhost:${port} [${env}]`);
});
```

Comment: can you paste the code from `src/server.js`? I think the problem might be with the server render.

Comment: if you perform server side render, you need to pass the store to the `Provider` on the server too

Comment: @AlexMoldovan I am new to Redux and express. I started my project with a starter project. From you're saying, I should wrap around <RouterContext {...renderProps}/> with Provider?

Comment: @AlexMoldovan I followed your solution and able to get it running without an error. But the "switchLanguage" I passed it, doesn't do anything

Comment: you mean the action is not dispatched from the Layout component?

Comment: @AlexMoldovan correct. But it somehow works fine on Client render.

Comment: since it's an event handler, it only gets called on the client, are you explicitly dispatching the action on the server render?

Comment: @AlexMoldovan I am trying to do server rendering. Server side renders the Client side code